# How do I format a string from an array of values in C?

Tags: c, c89

I've been using C# for the last few years, and right now I'm trying to write some C. I'm trying to format a string from an array of values. The "format string" and the array aren't known until runtime.

In C# I can invoke a variadic function with an array, like this:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication7
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string formatString = "{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}";
            string[] formatValues = new[] { "a", "b", "c", "d" };

            string formatted = String.Format(formatString, formatValues);

            //Do something with formatted (now looks like "a.b.c.d")
        }
    }
}
```

In C I've got this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

    int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
        char *formatString = "%s.%s.%s.%s";
        char *formatValues[] = {"a","b","c","d"};

        char *buffer = (char*)malloc(100 * sizeof(char));

        //This doesn't work.....
        sprintf(buffer, formatString, formatValues);

        //... buffer is junk

        return 0;
    }
```

How can I do this in C?

(Is there a nice function in the C standard library I can use to help me, or perhaps, is there a way to call a varargs function with an array?)

Please note, the number of arguments will never be greater than the length of the array I have. And the types will always be strings. So I might have

```
char *formatString = "My Formatted String %s.%s.%s";
char *formatValues[] = {"a","b","c","d","e"};
```

But I'll never have too few %s.

Note: the C has to work on GCC for Linux, and Visual Studio for Windows (C90).

Comment: Take a look at vsprintf - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/28d5ce15(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: What happens when you compile and run the code you gave? Do you get any errors?

Comment: I don't think what you want is possible in one step. You might want to run a loop and `sprintf()` and then `strcat()`. Also, please use `snprintf()` instead of `sprintf()` - it somewhat decreases the possibilty of buffer overrun errors.

Comment: @Code-Guru It runs but the buffer contains junk (in the debugger it's dX¥.(null).(null).)

Comment: @LeorA Smashing, thank you, vsprintf seems to work if I cast the formatValues array to a vs_list. I'll post that as an answer and see if there's some feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think C provides a standardized way to do this. If you understood the internal implementation of `<stdarg.h>` on your system, it would probably be possible to kludge up a system-specific solution involving *vprintf(3),* but I have a different, conforming kludge for you...

Something that would *work* would involve declaring an array of some large size, set the values that you have, and then just pass every element of the array at the call site, regardless of whether they are set.

```
char *a[5]; // or a[50], whatever you need

// assign the elements you actually have

printf(format_string, a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5]);
```

Comment: This is really clever. It's a great solution to my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The only type of array sprintf accepts is a null-terminated array of chars (ie a string).
This should work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char *formatStrings[]={"%s","%s","%s","%s"};
    char *buffer= (char*)malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
    char *formatValues[]={"a","b","c","d"};
    char *endofBuffer=buffer;
    int valueCount=4;
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<valueCount; ++i)
    {
        endofBuffer+=sprintf(endofBuffer, formatStrings[i], formatValues[i]);
        if (i<valueCount-1)
            endofBuffer+=sprintf(endofBuffer, "%c", '.');
    }
    printf("%s\n",buffer);
    return 0;
}
```